# why a outer element can't be found by filter(":visible") if setting inner element position:absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the element if it was detected by filter("visible").

We can see the inner picture is visible, but why the outer element `<a>` can't be found if setting `<img>` position:absolute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            position: absolute;
        }
        img {
            position: absolute; //the filter() works if i annotate this line
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#container a").filter(":visible").hide()
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <a href=""><img src="http://sudasuta.com/script/timthumb.php?src=http://sudasuta.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/he-British-Library-2.jpg&h=200&w=260&zc=1"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no reason for having `position: absolute;` on the `img` tag.

Comment: I was trapped by this unconscious mistake.

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.

If you make the `img` positioned absolutely, then the `a` no longer takes any space in the document, because the only thing in it doesn't contribute to its size, and so it's 0 high by 0 wide.

Doing anything to give the `a` element size will change the behavior. For example, adding `width: 1px` to the rule for the `a` element. (Example: [Not working](http://jsbin.com/pivapuro/1) | [Working with `width: 1px`](http://jsbin.com/pivapuro/2).)

Comment: Awesome spot! So adding a `width`/`height` to the a would work. I never knew this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that, when you set `position: absolute` in the `img`, the `img` element is taken out of the normal flow of the document. The consequence? your `a` will have a height of 0. `:visible` returns all elements that occupy space on the screen (neither are hidden, invisible or with effective height or width equal to zero).